# compare columns of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can I compare column B list values with column A list values and either leave column B list value or change it to NaN when column A value's list element is NaN?

I tried to search about it but only found similar questions which then where solved with the apply function but I don't really know how it works.

Here is an example how it should look at the end:

```
data = {"A":[[100, 333.3, np.NaN, np.NaN],[np.NaN, np.NaN,50, 25]],
       "B":[["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"], ["B1", "B2", "B3", "B4"]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

The output should be:

```
            A                     B

0 [100, 333.3, nan, nan] [A1, A2, nan, nan] 

1     [nan, nan, 50, 25] [nan, nan, B3, B4]
```

Comment: The basic idea is to iterate on each list and check if in the corresponding place in A you have a `NaN`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using for loop .

```
df.B=[[s if t==t else np.nan for t,s in zip(x,y) ]for x , y in zip(df.A,df.B)]
df
Out[74]: 
                        A                   B
0  [100, 333.3, nan, nan]  [A1, A2, nan, nan]
1      [nan, nan, 50, 25]  [nan, nan, B3, B4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can preprocess your data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data = {"A":[[100, 333.3, np.NaN, np.NaN],[np.NaN, np.NaN,50, 25]],
        "B":[["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"],    ["B1", "B2", "B3", "B4"]]}


# preprocess B and set np.NaN where needed:
b_data = data["B"]

for i,inner in enumerate(b_data):
    for idx,value in enumerate(inner):
        a = data["A"][i][idx]
        inner[idx] = a if np.isnan(a) else value


df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                        A                   B
0  [100, 333.3, nan, nan]  [A1, A2, nan, nan]
1      [nan, nan, 50, 25]  [nan, nan, B3, B4]
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. Can the loop be changed to compare the columns in the dataframe instead of on the original data?